# Windows Mobile 5 Modern Emulator

Tags: windows, emulation, windows-mobile-5.0

I need to bring back from the dead an app desined to Windows Mobile 5.

I tried to find an emulator but everything seems to be dead already.

Is there any emulator that can run Windows Mobile 5 on Windows 10 or Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Device emulator is also part of VS 2003 and 2008. If you have a msdn developer subscription, you can still download and install these.
At my time as technical support engineer I had running the device emulator stand alone edition as well as VS 2008 running with windows 10. You can even get active sync up and running.
Contact me directly if you need more details.

Regards

Josef

Comment: I have the original disks of VS 2008 and 2003 :). But these apps were run on Palm devices and now I don't have one, but some really light Windows 10 tablet. I prefer to not install the entire VS on the tablet (it has very low storage). Is there a way to get an stand alone version of the emulator? BTW, the app use Bluetooth and SD card, is the emulator can emulate these as well (the tablet has Bluetooth support)

Comment: The stand-alone emulator does not emulate BT, and Network emulation cannot be used any more since Windows Vista. SD Card emulation is done by using a shared folder between the emulated device and the host system. Best is you buy a compatible device. For example something like this https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-anzeige/mda-vario-3-von-t-mobile-windows-phone/1838071456-173-4244.

Comment: The stand-alone emulator does not emulate BT, and Network emulation cannot be used any more since Windows Vista. SD Card emulation is done by using a shared folder between the emulated device and the host system. Best is you buy a compatible device. For example something like this: the CN51 https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313&_nkw=intermec+cn51&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_odkw=intermec+nc51&_osacat=0. If you need to develop for company xyz, ask them for test device.

Comment: I need the app for me (personal use), and I need to run an existing app, not developing a new one. All the thing was to use existing devices (tablets, laptops, or phones) and not buying a compatible device. I can live without the BT, but the SD card emulation is necessary.

Comment: Is there a way to get a stand alone version of the emulator without entire VS?

Comment: you may use the local copy from h**ps://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vYkiLiTxBStqDz2eBGYA0hIrR5ZaX-tN?usp=sharing